# jquery conflict with angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs

I have jquery and angularjs in my `c#` project.
I see that I have to call angularjs before jquery to avoid conflict between them.

My **MasterPage.master**

```
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.8.2/angular-sanitize.min.js" integrity="sha512-JkCv2gG5E746DSy2JQlYUJUcw9mT0vyre2KxE2ZuDjNfqG90Bi7GhcHUjLQ2VIAF1QVsY5JMwA1+bjjU5Omabw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/metisMenu.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
<script src="Content/x-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="Content/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="Content/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/metisMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/styles/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/x-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-zrnmn8R8KkWl12rAZFt4yKjxplaDaT7/EUkKm7AovijfrQItFWR7O/JJn4DAa/gx" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link href="Content/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/waza.css" />
<script src="Scripts/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/typeahead-ci.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/validator.js"></script>
```

My **homepage.aspx**

```
<script src="Content/formvalidation/js/formValidation.js"></script>
<script src="Content/formvalidation/js/framework/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-leaflet-directive/0.10.0/angular-leaflet-directive.min.js" integrity="sha512-dtFpnbvMRGgxjWRrfWjqeiRwDk5iQR/d7FRIv5xs+7fIWzKI/376mEiYTcyfH1os/ed+BgMpIFO+p7rof14Hdg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="Scripts/app/app.js"></script>  -- angularjs file
```

My issue is even if i call angularjs before jquery in my project when I do some stuff in my homepage like modify an element in a table. After that I have this message on my page. There is other solutions to avoid conflict ? or I may do something wrong.

[image: error]

Comment: What conflict? If you load jQuery before angularjs then angular will use jQuery for `angular.element` internally

Comment: @charlietfl U can see in the picture '$ is not a function' for exemple because of angularjs use $ and for the project $ is not for jquery

Comment: angularjs **does not** use `$` by default. If you read the docs it will actually use jQuery internally for `angular.element` if jQuery is loaded before it is

Comment: @charlietfl Ok if angularjs doesn't use jquery by default why the only page where I use Angularjs I have this issue ? So if it's not angularjs do u have any suggestion to help me ?

Comment: Do you have link to live page?

Comment: @charlietfl I don't have